# Make a column with unique words using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe containing a column with repeated words for part of rows:

```
id source_value
1  Peter, Julia, Peter, Michael 
2  NULL
3  Michael, Sara, Michael
4  John
```

I need to create a column, where duplicate words in each row will be excluded:

```
id result_value
1  Peter, Julia, Michael 
2  NULL
3  Michael, Sara
4  John
```

What is the best way to do this with PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert source_value column to array using `split()` function then using `array_distinct()` function you can get distinct values.

Note: I used `transform()` function to trim white spaces of each element in source_value column after converting it to array.

```
>>> df.withColumn('source_value', split('source_value', ',')) \
    .withColumn("source_value", expr("transform(source_value, c-> trim(c))")) \
    .withColumn("source_value", concat_ws(',', array_distinct('source_value'))) \
    .show(truncate=False)

+---+-------------------+
|id |source_value       |
+---+-------------------+
|1  |Peter,Julia,Michael|
|2  |NULL               |
|3  |Michael,Sara       |
|4  |John               |
+---+-------------------+
```